# Separate a single line of 3 numeric values into 3 columns in Microsoft Excel and get an average

Tags: excel, serialization, excel-formula, multiple-columns, csv

I'm downloading a set of 3 values using Microsoft Data Streamer in Microsoft Excel via a serial input.
I get a single line of 3 values when I press the **print** button on the device.

It appears the printed values are in this order in a single line:

1. 3 empty spaces
2. number
3. 3 empty spaces
4. number
5. 4 empty spaces
6. number

I'm ensuring that based on cell format the values that print/upload are up to 3 decimal places.

Example:

```
63.140   179.655    79.870
```

For the first value I'm using this formula:

```
=LEFT($B8,SEARCH(".",$B8)+3)
```

For the second value I'm using this formula:

```
=MID($B8,10,10)
```

For the third value I'm using this formula:

```
=RIGHT($B8,SEARCH(".",$B8)+3)
```

I get each of the numbers listed above in a separate column.
When I try to take their average I get a `#DIV/0!` error.
I did convert the cell columns to numbers with 3 digits but still get the error.

I then tried to copy the values into another other cell and it says it's a text format.
Is there a way to ensure the values are numeric in the beginning or after the formula has been used?
Or can I convert the text to a number via a formula?

Are there alternate methods to separate these values without using the excel delimiter separation menu?

Thanks!

[Formula sample shown to extract value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMvVp.jpg)

[divide by zero error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7naeI.jpg)

Comment: Off topic: You got several outstanding question. Please revisit them and see if there is any which has an answer you can accept as being correct since that's how this site works. See the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) if you are unfamiliar with this.

Answer (score 0):

In case you got Excel 2013 or highter you could try to get the average directly:

```
=AVERAGE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(B8," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[node()]"))
```

---

If you got Excel 2010 (which it looks like looking at these screenshots), you could try:

```
=((--LEFT(B8,FIND(" ",B8)))+(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(B8," ",REPT(" ",LEN(B8))),LEN(B8)+1,LEN(B8))))+(--TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(B8," ",REPT(" ",LEN(B8))),LEN(B8)))))/3
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Excel 2007.

I found out that the formula was converting the values to a text format even though my output cell was formatted as a number cell up to 3 decimal places.

This is what worked and gave me actual numbers and an average for each row:

First Column (Cell: F8) =LEFT($B8,SEARCH(".",$B8)+3)

Second Column (Cell: G8) =MID($B8,10,10)

Third Column (Cell: H8) =RIGHT($B12,SEARCH(".",$B12)+2)

**I transferred these values to another 3 columns to get actual values rather than text:**

First Column (Cell: J8) =VALUE(F8)

Second Column (Cell: K8) =VALUE(G8)

Third Column (Cell: L8) =VALUE(H8)

**I then took the average of these cells and confirmed the answer was correct by verifying via the calculator tool in Windows.**

[screenshot of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvVhT.jpg)